# Automate these simple web application build tasks?

Tags: macos, web-applications, automation, terminal

In the process of creating a Desktop version of my Web app, I'd like to automate a number of tasks:

1. The folders a, b, c need to be copied from project/ to project/desktop/
2. I need to run this node.js command on a number of css files: "node lessc styles.less > styles.css"
3. I need to remove this line from my index.html file:
   `<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="../assets/css/styles.less">`
4. I need to add this line to my index.html file:
   `<link rel="text/css" href="../assets/css/styles.css">`

How do I write this in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using a short bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1.
cd project
for folder in a b c; do
    cp "$folder" "desktop/$folder"
done

# 2.
for less in *.less; do
    node lessc "$less" "${less%less}css"
done

# 3. + 4.
replace '<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="../assets/css/styles.less">' \
    '<link rel="text/css" href="../assets/css/styles.css">' -- index.html
```

The "replace" command used in 3 and 4 is only available if you have MySQL installed, which I assume you do have as a web developer. :)

Comment: Thx for the help, I'm getting there :)